# Is there a way to factorize the tree decoration of several trees?

Tags: forest, trees

I have a LaTeX document with several trees made with the `forest` package and would like to define a decoration style for these trees in a way that avoids code duplication. In other words, I would like to put the tree decoration settings (i.e: `for tree= {...}`) in a unique place—it would be more readable and easier to modify this way. My code looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}
\tikzset{
  my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

% ================= FIRST TREE
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    if={level()<2}{
      my rounded corners,
      draw=linecol,
    }{},
    edge={color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    if level=0{%
      l sep+=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      tikz={
        \path (!1.child anchor) coordinate (A) -- () coordinate (B) -- (!l.child anchor) coordinate (C) pic [draw, angle radius=20mm, every node/.append style={fill=white}, "based on"] {angle};
      },
    }{%
      if level=1{%
        parent anchor=south west,
        child anchor=north,
        tier=parting ways,
        align=center,
        font=\bfseries,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          align=left,
        },
      }{
        if level=2{
          shape=coordinate,
          no edge,
          grow'=0,
          calign with current edge,
          xshift=20pt,
          for descendants={
            parent anchor=south west,
            l sep+=-20pt
          },
          for children={
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!to tier=parting ways.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            font=\bfseries,
            for descendants={
              no edge,
            },
          },
        }{},
      },
    }%
  },
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

%================= SECOND TREE
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    if={level()<2}{
      my rounded corners,
      draw=linecol,
    }{},
    edge={color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    if level=0{%
      l sep+=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      tikz={
        \path (!1.child anchor) coordinate (A) -- () coordinate (B) -- (!l.child anchor) coordinate (C) pic [draw, angle radius=20mm, every node/.append style={fill=white}, "based on"] {angle};
      },
    }{%
      if level=1{%
        parent anchor=south west,
        child anchor=north,
        tier=parting ways,
        align=center,
        font=\bfseries,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          align=left,
        },
      }{
        if level=2{
          shape=coordinate,
          no edge,
          grow'=0,
          calign with current edge,
          xshift=20pt,
          for descendants={
            parent anchor=south west,
            l sep+=-20pt
          },
          for children={
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!to tier=parting ways.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            font=\bfseries,
            for descendants={
              no edge,
            },
          },
        }{},
      },
    }%
  },
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve such a thing ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know two ways to do this. The first way puts the customizations inside a style, therefore they will be applied to every `forest` environment for which you specify this style; the second way applies the given customizations to all `forest` environments inside a given TeX group—possibly the whole document.

## Customizations applied using a style

You can define a style with `\forestset` (the style is named `my forest` in the following example) and specify its name in the particular `forest` environments where you want it to be active:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}
\tikzset{
  my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  my forest/.style={
    for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    if={level()<2}{
      my rounded corners,
      draw=linecol,
    }{},
    edge={color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    if level=0{%
      l sep+=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      tikz={
        \path (!1.child anchor) coordinate (A) -- () coordinate (B) -- (!l.child anchor) coordinate (C) pic [draw, angle radius=20mm, every node/.append style={fill=white}, "based on"] {angle};
      },
    }{%
      if level=1{%
        parent anchor=south west,
        child anchor=north,
        tier=parting ways,
        align=center,
        font=\bfseries,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          align=left,
        },
      }{
        if level=2{
          shape=coordinate,
          no edge,
          grow'=0,
          calign with current edge,
          xshift=20pt,
          for descendants={
            parent anchor=south west,
            l sep+=-20pt
          },
          for children={
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!to tier=parting ways.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            font=\bfseries,
            for descendants={
              no edge,
            },
          },
        }{},
      },
    }%
  }}}

\begin{document}

\section{First tree}

\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\section{Second tree}

\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Customizations applied to all `forest` environments within a given TeX group

Using

```latex
\forestset{
  default preamble={...}
}
```

you can apply the `...` settings to all `forest` environments in the current TeX group. If used in the preamble, this will be applied to all `forest` environments in the document.

Example with the settings in the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}
\tikzset{
  my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    if={level()<2}{
      my rounded corners,
      draw=linecol,
    }{},
    edge={color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    if level=0{%
      l sep+=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      tikz={
        \path (!1.child anchor) coordinate (A) -- () coordinate (B) -- (!l.child anchor) coordinate (C) pic [draw, angle radius=20mm, every node/.append style={fill=white}, "based on"] {angle};
      },
    }{%
      if level=1{%
        parent anchor=south west,
        child anchor=north,
        tier=parting ways,
        align=center,
        font=\bfseries,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          align=left,
        },
      }{
        if level=2{
          shape=coordinate,
          no edge,
          grow'=0,
          calign with current edge,
          xshift=20pt,
          for descendants={
            parent anchor=south west,
            l sep+=-20pt
          },
          for children={
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!to tier=parting ways.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            font=\bfseries,
            for descendants={
              no edge,
            },
          },
        }{},
      },
    }%
  }}}

\begin{document}

\section{First tree}

\begin{forest}
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\section{Second tree}

\begin{forest}
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The output is identical as in the previous example.

Example where we do the settings inside a group, output one tree from this group (thus using the custom settings), then leave the group and output a second tree which therefore uses the default settings:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} % the tree in section 2 is rather wide
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\colorlet{linecol}{black!75}
\tikzset{
  my rounded corners/.append style={rounded corners=2pt},
}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\section{First tree}

{% \forestset settings local to the current TeX group
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    for tree={
    line width=1pt,
    if={level()<2}{
      my rounded corners,
      draw=linecol,
    }{},
    edge={color=linecol, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    if level=0{%
      l sep+=1.5cm,
      align=center,
      parent anchor=south,
      tikz={
        \path (!1.child anchor) coordinate (A) -- () coordinate (B) -- (!l.child anchor) coordinate (C) pic [draw, angle radius=20mm, every node/.append style={fill=white}, "based on"] {angle};
      },
    }{%
      if level=1{%
        parent anchor=south west,
        child anchor=north,
        tier=parting ways,
        align=center,
        font=\bfseries,
        for descendants={
          child anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          align=left,
        },
      }{
        if level=2{
          shape=coordinate,
          no edge,
          grow'=0,
          calign with current edge,
          xshift=20pt,
          for descendants={
            parent anchor=south west,
            l sep+=-20pt
          },
          for children={
            edge path={
              \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!to tier=parting ways.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            font=\bfseries,
            for descendants={
              no edge,
            },
          },
        }{},
      },
    }%
  }}}
%
% Tree in the same TeX group: it uses the settings we just set
\begin{forest}
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

}% Leave the group where we used custom \forestset{default preamble={...}}
 % settings.

\section{Second tree}

% This tree uses the default settings.
\begin{forest}
  [Concept
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [sub-concept
      [
        [method
        [submethod]
        ]
        [method
        [submethod\\details]
        ]
        [method
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]